# Why does the SD card stop logging without error?

Tags: arduino

The following sketch is for an Arduino Nano clone. It waits for a START command then collects data from an I2C slave, assembles it for logging on an SD card, writes it to the card, prints it to the serial monitor and repeats. I've tested and retested. The SD card logfile ALWAYS stops after logging the header and 3 out of 30 lines of data, but the serial monitor shows all the expected data. Never in any of my tests was an SD write error generated.

I'd appreciate any ideas as to why the SD stops logging and how to fix it.

Arduino Sketch

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>

// Uncomment the #define below to enable internal polling of data.
#define POLLING_ENABLED

//define slave i2c address
#define I2C_SLAVE_ADDRESS 9 

/* ===================================
        Arduino Nano Connections

  ESC (PWM) Signal    - Pin 9 (1000ms min, 2000ms max)
  S.Port Signal - Pin 10

  SPI Connections 
    MOSI = Pin 11
    MISO = Pin 12
    SCLK = PIN 13

   I2C Connections
     SDA = Pin A4
     SCL = Pin A5   

    Start/Stop Switches
    Start = Pin 2 => INT0
    Stop  = Pin 3 => INT1
  ===================================*/  

 Servo esc;    // Servo object for the ESC - PIN 9

 const unsigned long pause = 800; // Number of ms between readings
 const unsigned long testDelay = 30000; // Number of ms between tests

 const int CS_pin = 10; // Pin to use for CS (SS) on your board
 const int Startpin = 2;
 const int Stoppin = 3;
 const int readings = 3; // Number of readings to take at every step
 const int steps = 5; // Number of steps to stop the ESC and take readings
 const byte HALT = 0;
 int ESC = 0;
 int throttle = 0; 
 int increment;
 volatile bool STOP = 0; 
 volatile bool START = 0;
 const String header = "% Thr,Thrust,Curr,Volts,RPM,Cell1,Cell2,Cell3,Cell4,Cell5,Cell6";
 char buffer0[33]; // Buffer for I2C received data
 char buffer1[33]; // Buffer for I2C received data
 String logEntry = "         GOT  NO  DATA                            "; //52 bytes

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(); 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(Startpin, INPUT_PULLUP);  
  pinMode(Stoppin, INPUT_PULLUP);  
  // Attach an interrupt to the ISR vector
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(Startpin), start_ISR, LOW);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(Stoppin), stop_ISR, LOW);
  esc.attach(9, 1000, 2000);
  // attaches the ESC on pin 9 to the servo object and sets min and max pulse width
  esc.write(HALT); // Shut down Motor NOW!
  increment = 180 / (steps - 1);
  // Number of degrees to move servo (ESC) per step (servo travel is 0-180 degrees so 180 = 100% throttle)
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("         Thrust Meter I2C Master");
  //Print program name
  //Initialize SD Card
  if (!SD.begin(CS_pin)) {
   Serial.println("Card Failure");
  }
  Serial.println("Card Ready");
  //Write Log File Header to SD Card
  writeSD(header);
  Serial.println(header);
}

void loop() {
  if (START) {
    Serial.println("Start Pressed");
    while (!STOP) {
      for (throttle = 0; throttle <= 180; throttle += increment) {
        for (int x = 0; x < readings; x++) {
          if (STOP) {
            esc.write(HALT); //  Shut down Motor NOW!
            Serial.println("Halting Motor");
          } else {
            wait (pause);
            esc.write(throttle); // increment the ESC
            wait (200);
            ESC = throttle * 100 / 180;
            getData(buffer0);
            wait (100);
            getData(buffer1);
            String logEntry = String(ESC) + "," + String(buffer1) + "," + String(buffer0);
            writeSD(logEntry);
            Serial.println(logEntry);
          }
        }
      }
      for (throttle = 180; throttle >= 0; throttle -= increment) {
        for (int x = 0; x < readings; x++) {
          if (STOP) {
            esc.write(HALT); //  Shut down Motor NOW!
            Serial.println("Halting Motor");
          } else {
            wait (pause);
            esc.write(throttle); // increment the ESC
            wait (200);
            ESC = throttle * 100 / 180;
            getData(buffer0);
            wait (100);
            getData(buffer1);
            String logEntry = String(ESC) + "," + String(buffer1) + "," + String(buffer0);
            writeSD(logEntry);
            Serial.println(logEntry);
          }
        }
      }
      Serial.println("End of Test Pass");
      wait (testDelay);
    }
    esc.write(HALT); //  Shut down Motor NOW!
  }
}

void writeSD(String logdata) {
  File logFile = SD.open("NANO_LOG.csv", FILE_WRITE);
  if (logFile) {
    logFile.println(logdata);
    logFile.close();
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error writing log data");
  }
}

void wait(unsigned long i) {
  unsigned long time = millis() + i;
  while(millis()<time) { }
}

void start_ISR() {
  START = 1;
  STOP = 0;
}

void stop_ISR() {
  STOP = 1;
  START = 0;
}

void getData(char* buff) {
  Wire.requestFrom(9, 32);
  for (byte i = 0; i < 32 && Wire.available(); ++i) {
    buff[i] = Wire.read();
    if (buff[i] == '#') {
      buff[i] = '\0';
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

This is the SD card contents:

```cpp
% Thr,Thrust,Curr,Volts,RPM,Cell1,Cell2,Cell3,Cell4,Cell5,Cell6
0,-12,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
0,-12,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
0,128,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
```

This is the output from the serial monitor:

```cpp
         Thrust Meter I2C Master
Card Ready
% Thr,Thrust,Curr,Volts,RPM,Cell1,Cell2,Cell3,Cell4,Cell5,Cell6
Start Pressed
0,-12,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
0,-12,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
0,128,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
25,2062,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
25,2520,0.00,15.75,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
25,2710,0.00,15.75,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
50,519,0.00,15.75,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
50,216,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
50,2288,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
75,890,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
75,891,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
75,1386,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
100,2621,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
100,2424,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
100,692,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
100,3409,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
100,227,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
100,3349,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
75,2220,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
75,2249,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
75,509,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
50,1977,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
50,2986,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
50,546,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
25,3746,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
25,3337,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
25,3015,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
0,96,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
0,-12,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
0,-14,0.00,15.76,0,3.10,4.20,3.96,3.96,0.00,0.00
End of Test Pass
```

Comment: Does it work if you leave `logFile` constantly open?

Comment: Good idea. Just tried it. Same results. Too bad. I really thought you might have something. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: That was a guess to infer what is going on. Here's some more. How do you read the `SD` file to display its contents? what does `ls -la file_name` say wrt. the length of the file? what does `cat -A file_name` show? what happens if you write to a different file each time? did you try replacing the `sd card` with another one?

Comment: That's what I did. I opened the log at the top of the loop, and closed it at the end of the test run. Should have had 31 lines including the header, but still only had 4. There is about a second between entries. That should be plenty of time between writes.

Comment: I power down the Nano, put the card in my Mac, and read the contents with OpenOffice or a text editor. I've done multiple passes in the same file. Deleted and recreated the file. Always the same result. Will try a new faster card, just have to blow away the Raspberry Pi OS that's on it.

Comment: Nah, I mean, every time you invoke `writeSD` just construct (dynamically, with `String`) a different file-name, so that you open a different file-name each time. And see what happens.

Comment: @Patrick, I tried changing names, that didn't work. A new faster card did! I should have tried that earlier. Thanks for the good advice. Sorry to take up so much of your time.

Comment: Post an answer with your solution, and be sure to select it as accepted one, then :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem was to replace the SD card with a faster one. Once I did that the data logged as it should. Thanks Patrick for the suggestion.